# Find equation for a function that converges below identity function like the picture

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to come up with a function that behaves like this:

[image]

Basically, the function is below the identity function x=y, and some upper bound (here, it is 0.25). And there is a parameter that controls how close it is to the blue lines (x=y and upper bound). This seems simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: What is this parameter, this green line?

Comment: I would use f(x)=x/(x+1) as a start point. Put some constant to fit it to 0.25. Then do some modify to create a parameter.

Comment: What are the green and orange lines the graphs of?